# Why is my FM synth getting out of phase?

Tags: frequency-modulation, oscillator

I'm trying to create a software FM synth following the formula for frequency modulation:

$$
y(t) = A \cdot f_c(t + I \cdot f_m(t))
$$

Where $A$ is amplitude, $f_c$ the carrier function, $f_m$ is the modulator function, $I$ the modulator index.

I have two generators that read waves from buffers/wavetables, I do the following in pseudo-code in every sample:

```
freq = 220
oscA.set_phase(phaseA) 
  # internally the osc library does:
  # t = phaseA
  # t >= 0 ? t -= t|0 : t += 1 - (t|0);
  # osc.phaseA = t
oscA.set_frequency(freq)
  # internally the osc library does
  # oscA.freq = freq / srate
oscA.process()
  # internally the osc library does
  # i = (phase * bufsize)|0
  # t = phase
  # t >= 0 ? t -= t|0 : t += 1 - (t|0)
  # phase = t
  # signal = buf[i]
phaseA = oscA.phase

oscB.set_phase(phaseB)
oscB.set_frequency(freq + oscA.signal * freq * 12)   # 12 is the modulation index/intensity
oscB.process()
phaseB = oscB.phase

output = oscB.signal
```

The resulting sound is pretty much like other vst synth I desire, however the phase slowly desyncs and there is a slight flanging high pitched sound.

Is there a better implementation of frequency modulation? Any idea what I could be missing from my basic implementation? Soundwise its almost there, however other vsts implement FM without any flanging noise.

Comment: There's a lot missing in your pseudocode.  I cannot tell where the phase of the *"carrier"* oscillator or the *"modulation"* oscillator are actually determined, how the phase terms are incremented (as they must be for an oscillator) nor how the sinusoidal waveform is looked up from the resulting phase value.

Comment: Sorry for my poor pseudocode, I tried to improve it, will probably try and formulate the same question with a sinusoidal example where I find it suffers the same problem.

Comment: I don't think I suffer the same issues using sinusoidal functions, maybe the problem is how the library is calculating the buffer position and/or phase increments.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it, turns out its the modulating signal that is not a perfect sinewave (it has been converted from a single cycle waveform to FFT partials back to wave), if I replace it with a sin function it doesn't flange.